# Return a randomly generated sorted Array as a String. HOW?

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a class that returns a String to the main method. The String is supposed to contain 6 randomly generated numbers from 1-99, and the numbers are supposed to be sorted before they are returned. However it doesn't work at all and I've been sitting all day trying to figure this out. I am new to Java and would prefer to just give it up but it's a class at my university. The code looks like this:

package lab1;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab111 {
    private String rad;

```
public String getLottorad() {

    Random r = new Random();
    int[] tal = new int[6];


        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {//generating 6 numbers
        tal[i] = r.nextInt(99)+1;
        }
        int i,j,crap;
        for(i=0;i<100;i++) //trying to sort the generated numbers
            for(j=i+1;j<100;j++)
                if(tal[i]>tal[j])
                {
                    crap=tal[i];
                    tal[i]=tal[j];
                    tal[j]=crap;                
                }
        rad = String.valueOf(tal[i]); /*trying to turn the sorted numbers into an int*/



    return rad;
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("How many lottery lines do you want? :");
    Scanner tgb = new Scanner(System.in);
    int antal = tgb.nextInt();
    Lab111 l = new Lab111();
    for (int i = 0; i < antal; i++)
        System.out.println(l.getLottorad()); // printing the sorted strings

}
```

}

If someone could explain what I'm doing wrong it would be really appreciated. Me and a classmate that is on my level have been tearing our hair off all day.

Comment: Do not deface your question. You have an option to delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to change your code as below.

```
private String rad;

public String getLottorad() {

    Random r = new Random();
    int[] vek = new int[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        vek[i] = r.nextInt(22);
        rad = String.valueOf(vek[i]);
    }
    return rad;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("How many lottery lines do you want? :");
    Scanner tgb = new Scanner(System.in);
    int antal = tgb.nextInt();
    Lab111 l = new Lab111();
    for (int i = 0; i < antal; i++)
        System.out.println(l.getLottorad());

}
```

Comment: And why should one do all that stuff `getLottorad`, when you only return a single number?

Comment: I have just fixed the problem the code had.

Comment: The problem I've mentioned is still there.

Comment: Thanks for quick response! It did help so that I don't get any error messages, but the method now only prints 1 number, but the loop is written to generate 10. Surely this is something I've done wrong in the method but I am new to Java so this is some McGyver-shit!

Comment: Sooo, does anyone have an explanation why the method only generates one number now? I really don't get it..